# How to get this iOS Http Post Request to work?

Tags: android, ios, paypal, google-cloud-functions, httprequest

I am setting up a payout process for a driver in my app with Firebase Cloud Functions and Paypal. The url to be posted is the url of the actual cloud function in Firebase:

> https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout

[image: Firebase Functions screenshot]

When trying to send an HTTP Post Request, it doesn't seem to be working.  See the **payoutRequest()** and the **Response** code below:

**payoutRequest()**

```
let email = txtPayoutEmail.text!
    let uid = self.uid!
    
    // Prepare URL:
    let url = URL(string: "https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout")
    guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
    
    // Prepare URL Request Object:
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    // Set HTTP Request Headers
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Your Token", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("no-cache", forHTTPHeaderField: "cache-control")

    print("request = \(request)")
    
    // HTTP Request Parameters which will be sent in HTTP Request Body:
    let postString = "uid=\(uid)&email=\(email)"
    print("postString = \(postString)")
     
    // Set HTTP Request Body
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    
    // Perform HTTP Request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error ) in
        
        print("data: \(String(describing: data))")
        print("response: \(String(describing: response))")
        print("error: \(String(describing: error))")
        
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            // Read all HTTP Response Headers
            print("All headers: \(response.allHeaderFields)")
            // Read a specific HTTP Response Header by name
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                print("Specific header: \(response.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") ?? " header not found")")
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
        
        // Check for Errors
        if let error = error {
            print("Error took place \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
        if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Response data string: \(dataString)")
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
```

**Response**

```
request = https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout
postString = uid=kv8JRVBwAfS1tgD04lNeM9esVzI2&email=myiosapp@me.com
data: Optional(138 bytes)
response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000037d1c20> { URL: https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout } { Status Code: 400, Headers {
"Content-Length" =     (
    138
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "text/html; charset=utf-8"
);
Date =     (
    "Thu, 17 Sep 2020 01:00:50 GMT"
);
Server =     (
    "Google Frontend"
);
"alt-svc" =     (
    "h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\""
);
"content-security-policy" =     (
    "default-src 'none'"
);
"function-execution-id" =     (
    cmrwbktlroxl
);
"x-cloud-trace-context" =     (
    "a85aaacd578e60690581aa64ead13b23;o=1"
);
"x-content-type-options" =     (
    nosniff
);
"x-powered-by" =     (
    Express
);
} })
error: nil
All headers: [AnyHashable("content-security-policy"): default-src 'none', 
AnyHashable("Date"): Thu, 17 Sep 2020 01:00:50 GMT, AnyHashable("alt-svc"): h3-Q050=":443"; 
ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3- 
T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; 
ma=2592000; v="46,43", AnyHashable("Content-Type"): text/html; charset=utf-8, 
AnyHashable("Content-Length"): 138, AnyHashable("x-cloud-trace-context"): 
a85aaacd578e60690581aa64ead13b23;o=1, AnyHashable("Server"): Google Frontend, 
AnyHashable("x-powered-by"): Express, AnyHashable("x-content-type-options"): nosniff, 
AnyHashable("function-execution-id"): cmrwbktlroxl]
Specific header: text/html; charset=utf-8
Response data string: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Bad Request</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

If the request is successful, then it would show up in the PayPal Notifications for PayPal Sandbox at the below link, but it isn't.

[PayPal developer notifications link](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications/)

I don't have much experience in PayPal HTTP requests.

I have done the same thing as I am trying to do here but in Android and it works perfectly so I know this should work, other than the Post Request (I tried using examples online to match what i had for the Android app)

### Edit

**updated payoutRequest():**

***Code surrounded in ** ** is new code***

```
let email = txtPayoutEmail.text!
    let uid = self.uid!

    // Prepare URL:
    let url = URL(string: "https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout")
    guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }

    // Prepare URL Request Object:
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // Set HTTP Request Headers
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Your Token", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("no-cache", forHTTPHeaderField: "cache-control")

    print("request = \(request)")

    // HTTP Request Parameters which will be sent in HTTP Request Body:
    **let body = ["uid": uid, "email": email]** 
    print("body = \(body)")

    // Set HTTP Request Body
    **request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])**

    // Perform HTTP Request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error ) in

        print("data: \(String(describing: data))")
        print("response: \(String(describing: response))")
        print("error: \(String(describing: error))")

        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            // Read all HTTP Response Headers
            print("All headers: \(response.allHeaderFields)")
            // Read a specific HTTP Response Header by name
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                print("Specific header: \(response.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") ?? " header not found")")
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }

        // Check for Errors
        if let error = error {
            print("Error took place \(error)")
            return
        }

        // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
        if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Response data string: \(dataString)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

**Response:**

```
request = https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout
body = ["uid": "kv8JRVBwAfS1tgD04lNeM9esVzI2", "email": "driver@ryyde.com"]
data: Optional(0 bytes)
response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600001f0d6a0> { URL: https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Content-Length" =     (
        0
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Thu, 17 Sep 2020 04:41:29 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        "Google Frontend"
    );
    "alt-svc" =     (
        "h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\""
    );
    "function-execution-id" =     (
        cmrwtq89fdsr
    );
    "x-cloud-trace-context" =     (
        "f3fe884ca8499e7a10c7081ce222876e;o=1"
    );
    "x-powered-by" =     (
        Express
    );
} })
error: nil
All headers: [AnyHashable("Content-Length"): 0, AnyHashable("x-cloud-trace-context"): f3fe884ca8499e7a10c7081ce222876e;o=1, AnyHashable("Server"): Google Frontend, AnyHashable("x-powered-by"): Express, AnyHashable("function-execution-id"): cmrwtq89fdsr, AnyHashable("alt-svc"): h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43", AnyHashable("Date"): Thu, 17 Sep 2020 04:41:29 GMT, AnyHashable("Content-Type"): text/html]
Specific header: text/html
Response data string:
```

**EDIT 2**

When I run my code, I check the function logs in firebase/functions (read from bottom up - seems to go ok with the function activity)

[image: functions 1]

[image: functions 2]

**EDIT 3 - Charles Session results**

> URL   https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net Status  Sending
> request body… Notes   Transaction began prior to session being cleared,
> body content transmitted before the session clear has not been
> captured Response Code    200 Connection established Protocol HTTP/1.1
> TLS   TLSv1.2 (TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256) Protocol   TLSv1.2 Session
> Resumed   Yes Cipher Suite    TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 ALPN - Client
> Certificates  - Server Certificates   - Extensions     Method CONNECT Kept
> Alive No Content-Type  Client Address 127.0.0.1:57209 Remote
> Address   us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/216.239.36.54:443
> Tags  - Connection     WebSockets - Timing     Size    Request    1.77 KB (1,817
> bytes) Response   1.35 KB (1,379 bytes)

**EDIT 4 - Android code**

```
private void payoutRequest() {

    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setTitle("Processing your payout ...");
    progress.setMessage("Please Wait .....");
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();

    // HTTP Request ....
    final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    // in json - we need variables for the hardcoded uid and Email
    JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();

    try {
        postData.put("uid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        postData.put("email", mPayoutEmail.getText().toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Request body ...
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, postData.toString());

    // Build Request ...
    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout")
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Your Token")
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            // something went wrong right off the bat
            progress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            // response successful ....
            // refers to response.status('200') or ('500')
            int responseCode = response.code();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                switch(responseCode) {
                    case 200:
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                                "Payout Successful!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        break;

                    case 500:
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                                "Error: no payout available", Snackbar
                                        .LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    default:
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                                "Error: couldn't complete the transaction",
                                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }

            } else {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                        "Error: couldn't complete the transaction",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            progress.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I recommend using something like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see what the difference is between your working Android request and your non-working iOS request.

Comment: This is something I haven't come across.  What exactly does it do?  Does it take my android code and make it ios code compatible?

Comment: Haha, no, unfortunately not. It's a tool that lets you view and inspect all of your network requests and responses. You can capture your Android request and iOS request, view their raw headers and post bodies, etc., which will let you compare them to see where you're going wrong on the iOS end. I highly recommend you learn how to use it – it is _extremely_ useful for debugging http request issues and is widely used by iOS and Android devs.

Comment: I ran a request in Charles Proxy, i attached in EDIT 3 - the results.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    let body = ["uid": uid,
                "email": email]
     
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])
```

Comment: I tried the above, still not working, see in EDIT the new code and the result, above

Comment: Added EDIT 2 to show the function activity when running payoutRequest ...

Comment: @LizG Why is it not working? Which response status code are you expecting? Your response status code was 400 and now is 200. Maybe there's something outside of the scope of this function you're missing.

Comment: I dont think its getting the data. Im about to give up on this

Comment: which data are you expecting? It really looks like it's working. You should either post a documentation for this API you're using or your Android code. 

Your request is now working, but maybe you're just not sending enough parameters to make it work like you want it to

Comment: @LizG: if you have an answer, please add it as self-answer, rather than adding a question update.

Comment: @halfer This is not an answer. I was posting the Android code for the request i am trying to get working in iOS

Comment: @EdgarTamioHirama I posted in EDIT 4 the Android code for payoutRequest() that works but for some reason cant seem to write the equivalent code for IOS